# MVC Jquery DataTable Issue with updating data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

here is the link-http://mvcjquerydatatables.apphb.com/

my problem is when load for the first time datatable comes, but we create a data, it is not updating in dataTable. it shows the same data. if we stop and run again it comes

Any solution is deeply appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax call is caching.  Add this into your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     "dataType": 'json',
     "type": "POST",
     "cache": false,  // <= here
     "url": sSource,
     "data": aoData,
     "success": fnCallback
});
```

Comment: do u have any idea of implementing fnDraw with this. do u think it will sort the issue

Comment: Is there a refresh() method on the table you are using?  It isn't clear in your example.  It also doesn't seem to have the "cache": false, line that I can see.

Comment: no but i have kept create actionlink for navigation

Comment: It sounds as though the table you are using isn't being refreshed on the client.  Have you put a breakpoint in the ajax server side to make sure that it's being called?

Comment: i have put it come in server side

Comment: wen i refresh page i have put a breakside in server side code of dataTable. it hits their

Comment: But it doesn't hit the breakpoint otherwise?  It still sounds like an Ajax caching issue.

Comment: server side data is not refreshing it is showing the same data

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify.  Is the server side being called and it returns the same data from the server, or is the server side not being called at all except on page refresh?